# CheckBox inside CheckedTextView

Tags: android

Currently I'm using `CheckedTextView` for my `ListView`. I want to activate the checkbox only when i click on the `CheckBox` but not on the corresponding text. how to achieve such functionality in `CheckedTextView`?

EDITED:

I've found a way around about this problem above. I used `OnTouchListener` and on the `onTouch` method, checked if `event.getX()` is in a certain range on a view. If you have other ideas, please share. =)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, why can't you go for CustomAdapter for the list by creating a row design in some row.xml, where you can keep a TextView and and Checkbox separately in the row which will work as you expected.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. I just want to explore alternatives bec. in `CheckedTextView` you don't have to worry about `ListView`'s "recycle".

Comment: Recycle in the sense of Memory or any thing else ?